# How do I resolve string errors in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

```
tc[['Test']] = tc[['test']].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

`ValueError: StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA`

I removed `.fillna(0)`, then I get an error again. The code works on different computer.

How do I fix this?

Running: `pd. __version__` , `'1.5.2'`

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your dataframe and the desired result?

Comment: It seems like indexing is error  `[['test']]` are you sure you need double `[[`

Comment: This works:     tc1[['Tx_Test']] = tc1[['Tx_Test']].fillna(0).astype(int)......

This doesn't work:    tc[['Test']] = tc[['Test']].fillna(0).astype(int)

Comment: you should create a [mre] -- a small sample of the dataframe that can be copy-pasted to reproduce the error

Comment: The code is just big and has dependencies. I am just curious if its file related or version related.